# OpenGL ES 2 code not giving correct output

Tags: macos, opengl-es

I have a simple program to render a vec4 to a point on my texture.

Fragment shader is

```
#version 100
recision highp float;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 1.0);
}
```

Vertex Shader is

```
#version 100
void main() {
    gl_Position    = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

When I read the values from the texture, all the values appear to be 0.
I'm running this on a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) with macOS Sierra version 10.12.4
I have an Intel HD 4000 graphics card.

The issue I'm facing is that this code works perfectly on other Macs (Intel HD 3000, late 2011, Sierra 10.12.4).

Has anyone faced any similar issues? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a minimal/complete/verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: More specifically what geometry are you drawing? Assuming triangles then having all three vertices at the same coordinate = zero area = no color.